# Why doesn't dfrgui exe work in x86 target platform

Tags: c#

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = @"C:\windows\SysWOW64\dfrgui.exe";
    ExecuteAsAdmin(fileName);
}

public static void ExecuteAsAdmin(string fileName)
{
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            
    try
    {
        proc.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

I am trying to run dfrgui.exe from process.start(). I am using Visual Studio 2008 as my source code is compatible only with this. When I run this code nothing happens and dfrgUI doesn't show up. My target platform is x86 and I should work on it. Is there way I can call this dfrgui.exe from my code using x86 as target platform? I don't want to change this to either anycpu or x64 because my application is 32bit.

Comment: your application is 32bit - in 2021? ***why***?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at that exception you swallow. That might give you the reason.

Comment: i am not getting any exception, but disk optimizer dialog is not coming up.